# Limit a user group to a specific view created via InfoPath 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, infopath, permissions, view

I have created a new view called '*RequesterView*' (via InfoPath 2010) to add items to a issue tracking list. The purpose of this is to limit the visibility of certain fields such as '*Assigned To*', '*Due Date*' to the requesters.

How can I limit a certain user group to use only the *RequesterView* to add and edit items?

Right now the requester can change the view via the add/edit page's ribbon menu to get to the all columns view (See Screenshot below)

[image: See Screenshot]

PS: Im new to dev work with MS InfoPath.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the curent users group you will have to edit the Mainfest.xml file. Here is a tutorial that shows exactly how:

No code solution (personal preference):
http://claytoncobb.wordpress.com/2009/07/19/infopath-user-roles-in-browser-enabled-forms-using-groups/

Once you have done this, create a rule and based on the user create a rule to switch views on form load.

Code based (then administrator approved form):
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/8a449a5f-21fd-49a2-bb3c-1912fea79841/switch-views-based-on-a-person-sharepoint-user-groups-in-infopath-2010

Also, hide the view from being displayed in the toolbar (untick "show on the view menu when filling out this form") so users can change the view.